# how to set precision without header file without iomanip

Tags: c++, codeblocks

When I print the value of `max1`, I get rounded output.

Using `setprecision` does solve my problem, but I want to solve the problem without using additional header files like `iomanip`.

```
int main()
{
    long long int n, l;

    cin >> n >> l;
    long long int a[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         cin >> a[i];

    sort(a, a + n);

    double max1 = 0;
    max1 = 2*mmax(a[0] - 0, l - a[n - 1]);
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
     {
          max1 = mmax(max1,(a[i + 1] - a[i]));
     }
    cout << max1/2.0;
    //cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << max1/2.0;
}
```

I received output in rounded form.

Comment: Can you talk about why you don't want to use header files?

Comment: `long long int a[n];` is **not** valid C++; some compilers (inclucing GCC and MSVC) support VLA as extension, though. Don't rely on that, someone else with a different compiler might not be able to compile your code...

Comment: So what should i do if i want to store numbers having value more than 10^9 in an array

Comment: Some companies dont allow the use of additional library files

Comment: @Freez The problem is not long long. You can use that. The problem is that `n` must be a compile time constant value (which it is not in your program).

Comment: @Freez what is an **additional** library file?

Comment: @Freez `<iomanip>` is part of the standard library, just as `<iostream>` is, too, which you are using already (or where do you think `std::cin`/`std::cout` come from?). So if you don't fear the latter, then why the former?

Comment: Will u please tell me why i m recieving the output in rounded form.

Comment: hi guys can you please upvote this answer now as the question in itself was correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the precision of `std::cout` without `std::setprecision` using [the member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision):

```
 std::cout.precision(42);
```